# Why does chrome play the HTML5 video in bad quality when Firefox plays it in perfect quality

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video

I've been wondering why Chrome, with the HTML5 video tag, plays the .mp4 video in very bad quality. But however, in Firefox, it plays it in perfect quality. Does anyone know why this is?